# Book where technology is a banned form of magic

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book trilogy I started reading over 15 years ago where the main character was a ~15yr old boy that hadn't found his magic yet (magic was prevalent throughout the world), but he was getting by with mimicing the effects of magic via technology which was a banned school of magic (I think the school was called death magic or dead magic).  If I recall correctly he runs off after being discovered by his mother practicing said magic (moving a boulder using a simple fulcrum/lever combo).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[The Darksword Trilogy](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheDarkswordTrilogy)*

> A trilogy by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman consisting of Forging the Darksword, Doom of the Darksword, Triumph of the Darksword, and Legacy of the Darksword. Also has an associated Tabletop RPG, Darksword Adventures, and a (now hard to find) companion book, called The Darksword Companion.
>
> In the magical land of Thimhallan, Magic is considered to be the same as Life. Those born with no magic are considered Dead. As an ancient prophecy tells of the destruction of the world by one who is Dead, those born without magic are routinely killed. However, royal-born protaganist Joram manages to escape this fate. Joining with a group of unlikely allies such as the elderly scholar Saryon and the erratic trickster Simkin, he plans to forge the magic-consuming Darksword and retake his royal position, unaware that doing so may bring the prophecy to fruition.

For the sake of education, I found it via search terms of *trilogy boy uses technology to fake magic*.

Comment: @Valorum: We posted close to simultaneously. :-D

Comment: Yours was first because I was busy formatting my answer ;-)

Comment: For the record, I searched for 'fantasy trilogy technology is banned dead magic'

Comment: Always funny to see how Google works, because even if the computer I'm using now is a "new" (blank history) session, Darskword doesn't pop here with either of your queries :-)